# Steps involving in resizing UICollectionCell in swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I working on auto layout and size class enabled project.I tried to resize UICollectionViewCell width to make sure it fit for entire screen.

```
code:
 screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
 screenWidth = screenSize.width
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
            layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
            sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize{
                recentCollection.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
                return CGSizeMake(screenWidth, 200.0)
        }
```

[image]

I do not know am i working on right way?any help appreciated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set width of UICollectionView to 0 and update constraint in viewdidload() method

```
screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
screenWidth = screenSize.width
    var Constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: recentCollection, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: screenWidth)
    recentCollection.addConstraint(Constraint)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Math trick you can use without involving constrains!!!!

You will get one cell = any device width!

Number 1 = items count! You can tweak it independently from your total items count to feet more or less items in creen!!! For example / (Double(33)) on iPhone 4 will feet 33 items in 4 columns and 4 items per row! in iPhone 6 Pluse you will see same picture cells will scale up respecting 4 columns!

You can use this trick for sizing views and font dynamically and proportionally based on screen size or any self resizing content view!

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        var deviceSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
        var flexCell = sqrt(Double(deviceSize.width * deviceSize.height) / (Double(1)))

        return CGSize(width: flexCell , height: flexCell)

    }
```